# Promise.all is not resolving if second promise is added to promise array

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Given that promise1 and promise2 are correctly resolved with the below code:

```
export const getExistingPayments = async (payments: Payment[]) => {

  const promise1 = await getPayment(payments[0].paymentId)
  const promise2 = await getPayment(payments[1].paymentId)

  const results = [promise1, promise2]
  return results
}
```

Can anybody help explain why the below code would just hang, the promises are never resolved or rejected:

```
export const getExistingPayments = async (payments: Payment[]) => {

  const promise1 = getPayment(payments[0].paymentId)
  const promise2 = getPayment(payments[1].paymentId)

  const results = await Promise.all([promise1, promise2])
  return results
}
```

It might also be worth mentioning that when only one promise is passed to the Promise.all the promise is resolved as expected, the below code also works fine:

```
export const getExistingPayments = async (payments: Payment[]) => {

  const promise1 = getPayment(payments[0].paymentId)

  const results = await Promise.all([promise1)
  return results
}
```

Comment: Could be a number of reasons. Most likely that `getPayment` is causing a lock on some resource. `await`ing each call gives time for the lock to be released, but `Promise.all` allows for concurrent calls, meaning `promise2` hangs waiting for `promise1` to release its lock. But that's a total guess.

Comment: Promise.all resolves if all promises resolves and get rejected if any promise get rejected whether any single promise in array resolves or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This largely depends on what happens inside `getPayment`. In general, your second example should work, but there are cases when that does not happen, particularly, if the two `getPayment` calls, due to some internal operations wait for each-other, reaching a deadlock.

While based on the information you have given, we cannot tell you exactly what happens in your code, the solution that you apply should be that you ensure that `getPayment` calls will never cause a deadlock if they are executed asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I suspected, just wanted to check I hadn't missed anything obvious :) The issue was in a package that getPayment was consuming, substituting the library for a different one that does the same job has fixed the problem

Comment: @JamesAdcock excellent news, I'm glad the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, instead of assigning the result of the functions to a variables

```js
  const [results1, result2] = await Promise.all([
    getPayment(payments[0].paymentId),
    getPayment(payments[1].paymentId)
  ])
```